Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ perfectly normal with respect to smooth functions?
We know that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is perfectly normal, i.e. that for every pair of disjoint closed sets $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ there exists a continuous function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, 1]$ such that $A = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ and $B = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, but can we moreover find such an $f$ which is smooth?
Edit:
I have a candidate for $f$ now, just need to show that it is smooth. If we let
$\displaystyle d(x, A) = \inf_{a \in A} |x - a|$,
then my candidate function is
$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\exp\bigg(-\dfrac{1}{d(x,B)}\bigg)}{\exp\bigg(-\dfrac{1}{d(x,B)}\bigg) + \exp\bigg(-\dfrac{1}{d(x,A)}\bigg)}$.

$d(x,F)$ is not a smooth function.

I know, but I think $\exp(1/d(x, A))$ is.

@user920957 $\exp(1/d(x,A))$ need not be differentiable- take e.g. $A=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. here is its graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mi5lqc8zdw (the same is also true of $\exp(-1/d(x,A))$)

Your function is not going to be smooth for most choices of $A$ and $B$. But your idea will work if you replace $\exp(-1/d(x,A))$ by a smooth function that vanishes exactly on $A$, and similarly for $B$. The existence of such a function is proved in Theorem 2.29 of my Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2nd ed.).

By the way, this is a splendid book: buy it or diplomatically ask for it as a Christmas (or birthday or...) present!
